# Azure DevOps Server 2019 - custom State

Tags: azure-devops, state, customization

I have added a new custom state called "In Code Review" into Azure DevOps Server 2019. I did it by going through Visual Studio and importing/exporting the WIT for PBI. The WIT for PBI I updated was to add the following (in the relevant sections)

```
   <TRANSITION from="In Progress" to="In Code Review">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Resolve Issue" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="In Code Review" to="Pending Deployment to Test">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Resolve Issue" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="In Code Review" to="To Do">
     <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Resolve Issue" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
```

All of this worked fine, but the problem I am having is that whenever I set the state as "In Code Review", it seems to drop out of the backlog for our sprint and I get the following message

**"One or more items were removed because of your recent changes.
The following changes removed the items:
State was set to: In Code Review"**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you have to update the process configuration of your project ([Process configuration XML element reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/process-configuration-xml-element?view=azure-devops-2020)).

1. Export configuration: [Import and export process configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration?view=azure-devops-2020)
2. Add the new state and assign it to InProgress metastate within RequirementBacklog section: [Map WIT category workflow states to state categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/process-configuration-xml-element?view=azure-devops-2020#map-wit-category-workflow-states-to-state-categories).
3. Import the updated process configuration file.

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks a lot!